# Does Blur let you try to hide while in plain sight?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, dnd-3.5e, stealth, cover

This is a short one:

Can a rogue under the effects of blur spell, but in plain sight, make a hide check?

Hide says under concealment he can... but just doesn't sound right, does it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, the Rogue can't. There are two separate conditions that must be met:

> You need cover or concealment in order to attempt a Hide check

Blur provides this. However, the second condition is as follows:

> If people are observing you, even casually, you can’t hide.

And Blur does not help with that. You need a separate ability for Hiding in Plain Sight, such as the Ranger's or Shadowdancer's aptly named class features.

Answer (score 12):

**It depends: Is anyone watching him?**

[Blur](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/blur.htm) grants [concealment](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/combatModifiers.htm#concealment), which is necessary for using stealth (generally).

However, you need more than concealment to hide:

> **If people are observing you, even casually, you can’t hide.** You can run around a corner or behind cover so that you’re out of sight and then hide, but the others then know at least where you went.
>
> If your observers are momentarily distracted (such as by a Bluff check; see below), though, you can attempt to hide. While the others turn their attention from you, you can attempt a Hide check if you can get to a hiding place of some kind. (As a general guideline, the hiding place has to be within 1 foot per rank you have in Hide.) This check, however, is made at a -10 penalty because you have to move fast.

([Source](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/hide.htm), emphasis added)

So, if your rogue is alone in an open field, the Blur spell gives him just enough camouflage that he can attempt a hide check.

On the other hand, if someone is watching him, Blur won't allow him to suddenly disappear.

Somewhere between the two, the rogue can pull the old "Hey, look over there" trick by making a bluff check, and then attempt to hide using Blur.

In general, there's probably enough clutter in the environment to make this kind of thing plausible. The rogue is hard to see, so if there's something to help conceal him, he uses it to hide.

Of course, if you're actually fighting in a featureless plain, you may want to add a situational modifier...